# VM ware player Ubuntu post Installation problem- VT-x not in BIOS on lenovo T430

Tags: server, virtualization, vmware, vmware-player

I am getting the following error:

"This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled"

When I went into BIOS to change these, I did not find any option like "VT-x"
Ubuntu version-14.04.01
VM- VM ware player
Laptop-Lenovo T430
OS already installed-Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: See [this article](http://amiduos.com/support/knowledge-base/article/enabling-virtualization-in-lenovo-systems), it's called "Virtualization Technology" in BIOS

Comment: Thanx @Serphiroth

Comment: You're welcome @Prabodh Hend